# Dynamodb: does delete count against read or write capacity?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I haven't able to find documentation within Amazon on this: does anyone know if the delete operation counts against your read or write capacity?

I had expected it would count as a "write", but the behavior I'm seeing in testing seems to indicate the opposite.  Can someone confirm this?

Comment: Which behavior let you conclude that a delete operation isn't counted as a write operation?

Answer (score 19):

Good question - while this doesn't seem to be specified explicitly, there are still two strong hints towards being counted as a write operation (as one would expect indeed):

1) Section *Time Series Data and Access Patterns* within [Provisioned Throughput Guidelines in Amazon DynamoDB](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/BestPractices.html) addresses efficient deletion and refers to affected write throughput:

> Deleting an entire table is significantly more efficient than removing
>   items one-by-one, which essentially doubles the write throughput as
>   you do as many delete operations as put operations.

2) Section *Responses* within the [DeleteItem API](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_DeleteItem.html) lists the return value *ConsumedCapacityUnits* and refers to write capacity units:

> The number of write capacity units consumed by the operation. This
>   value shows the number applied toward your provisioned throughput. For
>   more information see [Provisioned Throughput in Amazon DynamoDB](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithDDTables.html#ProvisionedThroughput).

Comment: Two years later, the article behind the link has a clear explanation: "When you issue a DeleteItem request, DynamoDB uses the size of the deleted item to calculate provisioned throughput consumption."

Answer (score 10):

**Yes, it does**. The documentation clearly says:

> `PutItem`, `UpdateItem`, and `DeleteItem` allow conditional writes, where
>   you specify an expression that must evaluate to true in order for the
>   operation to succeed. If the expression evaluates to false, DynamoDB
>   will still consume write capacity units from the table:
>
> - **If the item exists, the number of write capacity units consumed
>     depends on the size of the item.** (For example, a failed conditional
>     write of a 1 KB item would consume one write capacity unit; if the
>     item were twice that size, the failed conditional write would consume
>     two write capacity units.)
> - **If the item does not exist, DynamoDB will
>     consume one write capacity unit.**

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/CapacityUnitCalculations.html#ItemSizeCalculations.Writes

Comment: link has moved to: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ProvisionedThroughput.html#ProvisionedThroughput.CapacityUnits.Write