# In DynamoDb does Time To Live deletion count against write capacity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, ttl

I failed to find in the TTL documentation about whether or not Time To Live deletion count against write capacity ?

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386456/dynamodb-does-delete-count-against-read-or-write-capacity) that a regular delete does, might it be the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deleted record by `TTL` doesn't consume any write capacity unit and nothing.

[Reference](https://www.gopiportal.in/2018/12/aws-dynamodb-automatically-delete-old.html)

> TTL for DynamoDB allows you to define when items in a table expire so that they can be automatically deleted from the database without using any Write capacity units.